# layout() on manually-inflated View

Tags: android, layout, view

In an `Activity`, I am manually inflating a `View` object from XML as follows:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (this);
    View topView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.topview_layout, null);
```

I won't be adding the view to any display hierarchy, but rather using it to generate bitmaps which I will then display.  Since those bitmaps will be the size of my (main) screen, I try to cause the layout to occur:

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService (Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                        .getDefaultDisplay();
    topView.measure (display.getWidth (), display.getHeight ());
    topView.layout (0, 0, display.getWidth (), display.getHeight ());
```

(It is getting the proper size of the display in the above code.)

`topView` is a `LinearLayout` which contains a few other views.  One of them is an `ImageView`:

```
    ImageView childView = (ImageView) pageView.findViewById (R.id.textArea);
```

However, this view never seems to be informed about its dimensions after the call to `layout()`:

```
    int childViewWidth = childView.getWidth ();
    int childViewHeight = childView.getHeight ();
```

(The dimensions retrieved by the above code are 0,0.)

All of the above code occurs linearly, and is called from within my Activity subclass' `onCreate()` method.

The layout XML I'm testing with is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would most appreciate any clues!

**NOTE:** Edited to add the layout XML and the `measure()` call pointed out as missing by [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call measure() before you call layout().

Comment: Thanks!  That's clearly something that was missing and I did add it--but I'm still not getting the right answer.  Now I'm getting dimensions of 63,0 where I should be getting something more like 480,780.  I don't think it's a problem in the layout XML because the preview in Eclipse looks perfect and the layout I'm testing with is very basic.  Can you think of any other gotchas here?

Comment: Edited the question to include `measure()` and the layout XML.  As a correction to my numbers above, once I simplified the XML to what's now in the question, the numbers went back to 0,0.

Comment: You are not calling measure() properly, read the documentation, you need to use MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(). You cannot just pass a width and a height.

Comment: Aha, missed that.  Of course it works now.  Many thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

First thing is inflate won't consider the layout parameters that you have specified in the xml. You can fix that by using

```
inflater.inflate( R.layout.top_view_layout /* resource id */,
                  parentView,
                  false /* attachToRoot */);
```

This will make sure that you are using the match_parent for both width and height.

OR

If you don't want to do that, then you should set the LayoutParams for the inflated view first.

P.S.: AFAIK, the layout method will take the parameters which are screen area available for display (left, top, right, bottom), but it will consider original size of the view for displaying (which is 0,0 in your case).